# JSX, can't show the correct link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to open in a new tab a URL retrieved from an API. It's basically a shortened URL. But when I try to add it to the href attribute of my , it returns me something like:

localhost:3000/[the correct shortened url]

or if I'm deploying the website:

[my website url]/[the correct shortened url]

Here's my component, where the link is the one with the "shortened-url" className:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/ModalUrl.scss";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";

const ModalUrl = ({ modalClass, setModalClass, shortenedUrl }) => {
  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalClass("hidden");
  };

  return (
    <div className="modal-and-background">
      <div className={`dark-background ${modalClass}`}></div>
      <div className={`modal-url ${modalClass}`}>
        <h1>Your URL is ready!</h1>
        <a href={shortenedUrl} className="shortened-url">
          {shortenedUrl}
        </a>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button className="btn-close" onClick={closeModal}>
            CLOSE
            <CloseIcon className="close-icon" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModalUrl;
```

Thank you!

Comment: `[the correct shortened url]` starts with `http://` or `https://`? or is it just `my.domain.com/something`?

Comment: If you don't include the full URL to an `href` attribute, it appends it to the current URL. I.e. `href="test"` will be `http://localhost:3000/test`. But `href="http://www.google.com/test"` will, as expected, navigate to that full URL. Also, if you want a new tab, you should include `target="_blank"`.

Comment: It starts with https://

Comment: please shortenedUrl value.

Comment: @juzello Given the behaviour you are saying it seems that *something* is wrong with the value. Unfortunately if you replace the actual value with `[invented stuff]` there is no way to see what's wrong. You will have to show us an *actual* URL that shows the behaviour. Replace your shortened URL with `https://example.com` or something. If that works try to see the differences between that url and your shortened urls... maybe there is a space/zero-width space at the beginning or something like that